# Joint density of RV with different densities

Tags: probability, density-function

Two random variables X and Y are independent, X is U(1, 2) and Y has a density function $2xI(x\in(0, 1))$. Find joint density of random variables $X^2$ and Y/X

I have some troubles in understanding of the approach where there are more than 1 random variable, I've been trying to use independence, but it is not the same as in 1-dimensional case where it is just product of density functions...

Comment: Write down $f_{X,Y}$ first and then  make  a change of variables.